# How to write test case for NoHostAvailableException in lagom with Scala?

Tags: scala, cassandra, lagom

I have a partial function as `exceptionHandler` which matches the corresponding exception and throws accordingly.
I am supposed to write a test case for `NoHostAvailableException`, but I am unable to throw the exception using mocking.

I have made already a mock server which makes embedded Cassandra down in Lagom.

### This is the partial function.

```
private val handleException: PartialFunction[Throwable, Future[List[MonitoringData]]] = {
    case noHostAvailableException: NoHostAvailableException => throw new CassandraNotAvailableException(TransportErrorCode
        .fromHttp(Error.CassandraNotAvailableErrorCode), Error.ErrorMessageForCassandraNotAvailable)

    case _ => throw new TransportException(TransportErrorCode.InternalServerError, Error.ErrorMessageForInternalServerError)
}
```

### This is the test case.

```
"not be able to interact with the database in" {
    when(mockReadDAO.getData)
        .thenThrow(NoHostAvailableException)
    assert(thrown.isInstanceOf[NoHostAvailableException])
}
```

The compiler doesn't take `NoHostAvailableException` as value.

Comment: Why did You use sca - Service Component Architecture tag?

Comment: I was adding Scala tag but my mistake it leaves out to sca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the difference between a **type**

```
NoHostAvailableException
```

and a **value**

```
new NoHostAvailableException(...)
```

in

```
val e: NoHostAvailableException = new NoHostAvailableException(...)
```

Conceptually, this is similar to the difference between type `Int` and value `42` in

```
val i: Int = 42
```

The meaning of the error

```
class com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException is not a value
```

is telling us we are using a type in a position where value is expected. Hence try

```
when(mockReadDAO.getData).thenThrow(new NoHostAvailableException(...))
```

instead of

```
when(mockReadDAO.getData).thenThrow(NoHostAvailableException)
```

Because `NoHostAvailableException` constructor takes `java.util.Map` as argument, try providing empty `java.util.HashMap` like so

```
val emptyHashMap = new java.util.HashMap[InetSocketAddress, Throwable]() 
when(mockReadDAO.getData).thenThrow(new NoHostAvailableException(emptyHashMap))
```